# Testing child element in nested driven template form

Tags: angular, nested-forms

I need to have nested template driven form and I used this guide to do it : 
[Angular: Nested template driven form](https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475)

Unfortunately as the first comment in the article is saying, when I tried to test my component I uncounterd this error :

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ControlContainer -> NgForm]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ControlContainer -> NgForm]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgForm!
```

It seems that since the child component need to use the existing ngForm from is parent it can't be tested on is own.

This [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template-pc8kjp) is showing what i'm trying to say. The AddressComponent is the child and AppComponent the parent.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `AddressComponent` requires an existing NgForm, you need to provide it as part of your test setup:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [FormsModule],
   declarations: [AppComponent, AddressComponent, HelloComponent],
   providers: [
     { provide: NgForm, useValue: new NgForm([], []) }
   ]
});
```

---

This resolves the error, but I have never done this before. I can make not comment on the downstream impacts of this. Long-term, you may want to implement your own `MockNgForm` class and then use an instance of that instead.